# Suppressing console output an errors while running Shell Script

Tags: shell, package, rpm

I am trying to output list of all running services, corresponding package and status on my Linux (Centos) box using below code snippet:-

```
for i in $(service --status-all | grep -v "not running" | grep -E running\|stopped |  awk '{print $1}'); do
packagename=$(rpm -qf /etc/init.d/$i)
servicestatus=$(service --status-all | grep $i | awk '{print $NF}');
echo $tdydate, $(ifconfig | sed -En 's/127.0.0.1//;s/.*inet (addr:)?(([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*).*/\2/p'), $i, $packagename, $servicestatus >> "$HOME/MyLog/running_services.csv"
done
```

However, when I run the script, I get errors on console like:-

```
error: file /etc/init.d/cupsd: No such file or directory
error: file /etc/init.d/hald: No such file or directory
error: file /etc/init.d/lvmetad: No such file or directory
error: file /etc/init.d/postmaster: No such file or directory
```

Probably, this is when it tries to find service names in init.d directory. However, this is not true for all services. 
Now, how can I suppress this console output? I don't want to see this on console. Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap the entire thing in parantheses and do a `2>/dev/null`

```
(
...
script
...
) 2>/dev/null
```

-That will run the script / snippet in a subshell.

See [this page](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/redirecting-stderr-to-stdout/) for more info on redirecting.

Answer (score 1):

To suppress `stdout` and `stderr`, you simply redirect the output like this: `command >/dev/null 2>&1`.

The first redirection `>/dev/null` will redirect the standard output to `/dev/null`, which will suppress it. This standard output are things that are written to the screen by commands, not errors (e.g. when executing `echo "hello"`, the `hello` will be a line of `stdout`).

The second redirection `2>&1` will couple `stderr` or standard error to the same location as standard output (so also to `/dev/null`).

A note on the notation: there are three standard file descriptors in linux (although I think you can create more, not sure). 1 resembles standard output, 2 standard error and 0 standard input. So you could also redirect standard error (i.e. error messages) to a log file, like this: `2>/path/to/log/file.log`.

Google for file descriptor for more information.

So you could, as pacman-- suggested wrap the entire code and redirect the output but you could also call your script like this: `bash script.sh >/dev/null 2>&1` which is more elegant because you can execute the script without the last redirection to debug or something like that, at least in my opinion.